# Is there any method to hide shader used in web application from being inspect by shader editor or other tools

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader

I am digging 3D web application for VR. And I want to hide my shader from being inspected by firefox shader editer and webGL inspector. I used the way to uglify the shader and put the shader in a return function rather than in a var. But none of them works.

So, is there any method to hide web application's shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple, no there isn't

Just printing out the shaders is pretty easy. All someone has to do is write an extension that does this

```
WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.shaderSource = function(origFn) {
  return function(shader, src) {
    console.log(src);
    origFn.call(this, shader, src);
  };
}(WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.shaderSource);
```

Even if you did find a way to prevent someone from looking at the shader in the inspector they could just as easily run system level tools like [Microsoft's PIX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pix/2017/01/17/introducing-pix-on-windows-beta/), or [Apple's OpenGL Profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2178/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007990). They could even run the browser using [OSMesa](https://www.mesa3d.org/osmesa.html) and compile it to print out the shaders. Chrome already runs with OSMesa as part of their testing setup. It would be trivial to make it print out the shaders, then use it to run/view your website.

The better question is why do you care? People inspect shaders all the time, [even in AAA games](http://www.adriancourreges.com/blog/). People can decompile assembly language if they want. Your shaders are not special. You're wasting your time trying to prevent them from being inspected.

Comment: well, I just want to find a way to hide shaders from those common tools like webGL inspector and firefox shader editor

Comment: People will just fix the tools

Comment: By the way, ur answer is hurt.

Comment: It's wasn't meant to hurt. It's meant to help prevent you wasting time in a futile effort.

Comment: Mind to share your solution, CyantigrisZ ? It would help others (me included!)

Comment: I just delete the instance right after using it. The idea is similar with garbage clean. Hope it's not too late.

Comment: deleting the instance doesn't help with the code posted in this answer